# 'No python at' error preventing anything from running - python pycharm

Tags: python, pycharm

I had been using a 32bit version of python on my 64bit system so changed to the 64 bit version. Ever since I have getting the following error when trying to run anything:

```
No Python at 'C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\python.exe'
```

I've tried uninstalling python and pycharm, then reinstalling but to no avail.

Python is installed to 'C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37', not \Python37-32 but I've not been able to figure out how to change this.

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: is python path present in environment variable?

Comment: ahh thanks, set the PYTHONPATH variable and it's working

Comment: check this link https://superuser.com/questions/143119/how-do-i-add-python-to-the-windows-path, if `PATH` is not present then create it.

Comment: or you could use anaconda python, it is better and while installing you will get an option to include python in `PATH`. anaconda python https://www.anaconda.com/distribution/#download-section

Comment: PyCharm obviously still expects the 32bit interpreter that it was configured for at some point. You'll have to remove the 32bit config and create a new one for the 64bit interpreter. See [this link](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/configuring-python-interpreter.html) for a general overview and [this link](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/configuring-local-python-interpreters.html) for how to configure a system interpreter specifically.

Comment: @Vikas Gautam yeah, except anaconda broke everything during its uninstallation

Answer (score 20):

You can first find the location of your "python.exe" file, then copy that

Next you have to edit the "pyvenv.cfg" file and paste the location of your python.exe file on the "home =" spot

Comment: And where is pyvenv.cfg file??

Comment: In my case "pyvenv.cfg" was located in virtual environment directory.

Comment: This is the error I encountered in Visual Studio Code. Updating new python.exe path in  `pyenv.cfg` file fixed the issue.

Answer (score 7):

Easy solution:

you have to make sure you have Requirements.txt file .

Next , delete your old environment folder example 'env', "venv" or what ever you called it.

then run the following commands:

```
pip install virtualenv
```

## Python 2:

```
$ virtualenv env
```

## Python 3

```
$ python3 -m venv env
```

Active your virtual environment by doing:

For windows

```
env\Scripts\activate
```

Next Do:

```
pip install -r Requirements.txt
```

There you have it, it should work....

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem,
if you are not working on venv then create a new folder another place away from the venv folder and then In your IDE change the directory and run it again.
but if you are in venv you need to install requirement and run venv in the terminal.

python -m venv project_env
env\Scripts\activate.bat